# How can I prove this statement? If $(a,b)=d$ and $a=qb+r$ then prove $d\mid r$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can I prove this statement? If $(a,b)=d$ and $a=qb+r$ then prove that $d\mid r$.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange!  Please post not only a question but also your thoughts about it.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**
$$r=a-bq$$
and $d|a,d|b$...